# Removing control characters from a UTF-8 string

Tags: c#, string, utf-8, control-characters

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762/how-do-you-remove-invalid-hexadecimal-characters-from-an-xml-based-data-source-pr) question but it removes all valid `utf-8` characters also (returns me a blank string, while there are valid `utf-8` characters plus control characters). As I read about `utf-8`, there's not a specific range for `control characters` and each character set has its own `control characters`.

How can I modify [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762/how-do-you-remove-invalid-hexadecimal-characters-from-an-xml-based-data-source-pr) solution to only remove `control characters` ?

Comment: You know, with a few lines of code (what exactly is a utf-8 string?) and a small sample of the text this would start to look like a real question.

Comment: real string is an Arabic `utf-8` string with some semicolon and control characters. I have provided a link to the most similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762/how-do-you-remove-invalid-hexadecimal-characters-from-an-xml-based-data-source-pr

Comment: How do you define control characters? Those with codepoint `<32`?

Comment: @CodeInChaos: I found it is not about real control characters. Any special character like `"`, `;` etc makes problem. I'm trying to set the string as a `HttpHeader` but get this exception: `Specified value has invalid Control characters`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think the following code will work for you:

```
public static string RemoveControlCharacters(string inString)
{
    if (inString == null) return null;
    StringBuilder newString = new StringBuilder();
    char ch;
    for (int i = 0; i < inString.Length; i++)
    {
        ch = inString[i];
        if (!char.IsControl(ch))
        {
            newString.Append(ch);
        }
    }
    return newString.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I still get `Specified value has invalid Control characters.` exception while trying to set the string as a `HttpHeader`.

Comment: @Xaqon It didn't work for all control characters. I have changed the condition to `!char.IsControl(ch)` and now it should work for you.

Comment: I found the problem, it is not about real `control characters`. Any special character like `\"`, `;` etc makes problem. I have no idea how to remove them from a `utf-8` string.

Comment: @Xaqron What is a _special_ character in your case? Any non alphanumeric? You should define these special characters and change the condition.

Comment: For example 1563 is a `;` and makes problem. I want to exclude all not alphabetical characters in all languages.

Comment: @Xaqron: use `char.IsLetter()` method.

Answer (score 25):

This is how I roll:

```
Regex.Replace(evilWeirdoText, @"[\u0000-\u001F]", string.Empty)
```

This strips out all the first 31 control characters. The next hex value up from \u001F is \u0020 AKA the space. Everything before space is all the line feed and null nonsense.

To believe me on the characters: http://donsnotes.com/tech/charsets/ascii.html

Comment: it would only filter for ASCII (UTF-8 C0 Controls but without "delete (rubout)") but the question is about UTF-8. There you have more control chars (UTF-8 C1 Controls).

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use the string as a query string, you should consider using the `Uri.EscapeUriString()` or `Uri.EscapeDataString()` before sending it out.
Note: You might still need to pull out anything from char.IsControl() first?