# Parsing string to array using Regex in c#

Tags: c#, regex, string-parsing

im currently making an c# application that receives a string from an serialport, and i need to parse this data so i can do stuff with it.

The strings that are send through the `SerialPort` are formatted like this:

```
*NTF,CTRL,SQL,OPEN,+,-66*NTF,CTRL,DBUSY,ON,+,-63*NTF,CTRL,DBUSY,OFF*NTF,CTRL,SQL,CLOSE*
```

now im wondering how i can split this string into segments on the `*` symbol,
i have made a couple attempts at this myself but couldnt figure it out.

### The attempts i made are:

```
String[] tmp = data.ToString().Split('*');
foreach(String word in tmp)
{
    if (word.Contains(",80") || word.Contains(",81"))
    {
        COM_PORT_INFO_BOX.Text += word + "\r\n";
    }
}
```

### which gave me:

```
NTF,CTRL,SQL,OPEN,+,-66
NTF,CT RL,DBUSY
,ON,+,-6
3
NTF,CT
RL,DBUSY
,OFF NTF,CT
RL,SQL,C
LOSE
```

### i have also tried:

```
var regex = new Regex('*'+".+"+'*');
var matches = regex.Matches(data);
```

But this gave me an error.

### What i want to achieve:

### The formatted string to look like this:

```
NTF,CTRL,SQL,OPEN,+,-66
NTF,CTRL,DBUSY,ON,+,-63
NTF,CTRL,DBUSY,OFF
NTF,CTRL,SQL,CLOSE
```

### EDIT:

I have solved the problem by having this piece of code:

```
SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
data += sp.ReadExisting().ToString();
string[] tmp = data.Split(new char[] {'\u0002','\u0003'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (string line in tmp)
{
    if (line.Contains(",80") || line.Contains(",81") || line.Contains(",RXVCALL"))
    {
        COM_PORT_INFO_BOX.Text += line.Substring(1) + "\r\n";
        data = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: "prefferably with regex" Why?

Comment: Read about `string.Split` method.

Comment: because i know that its better with regex i tried doing it using split normally but then it would put everything at kind of a random point in a new array field

Comment: You have three asterisks in the example, so would you want just the text between the first two (i.e. pairs of delimiters), or also the text between the second and third?

Comment: also between the second and third and counting upwards

Comment: What have you tried? What was the result? What is the expected output? Please put more effort into asking a question if you want others to make an effort in answering

Comment: or ofc if thats easier removing the first asterisk and the found text after saving it

Comment: Does the text always start and end with an asterisk?

Comment: What's inside `data`?

Comment: inside data is the datareceived from COM1

Comment: @GiovanniLeGrand You have some problem with your data. `YOUR_EXAMPLE_STRING.Split('*')` gives the exact result you wanted (but with two empty entries - see `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` in D.Stanley's answer to resolve that).

EDIT: see for yourself: http://csharppad.com/gist/8234ba34d9df2170d08c

Comment: `String.Split()` is not some new brittle technology. It's pretty straightforward, and it's not going to mess up unless you give it bad input. Double-check the string you are actually getting and make sure it doesn't have, e.g., embedded newlines or extra asterisks.

Comment: exact data im receiving is: *NTF,CTRL,SQL,OPEN,+,-64*NTF,CTRL,DBUSY,ON,+,-63*NTF,CTRL,DBUSY,OFF*NTF,CTRL,SQL,CLOSE*NTF,CTRL,SQL,OPEN,9,-68*NTF,CTRL,DBUSY,ON,+,-63*NTF,CTRL,DBUSY,OFF*NTF,CTRL,SQL,CLOSE*NTF,CTRL,SQL,OPEN,+,-63*NTF,CTRL,DBUSY,ON,+,-63*NTF,CTRL,DBUSY,OFF*NTF,CTRL,SQL,CLOSE stackoverflow removed the asteriks before the whole line

Comment: You might need to pull it up in a text editor or hex editor and make sure there are no special characters. I am concerned that the text is switching between italics and non-italics, indicating that there's something special in your input (probably apostrophes, but who knows).

Comment: @GiovanniLeGrand Works for that string as well - http://csharppad.com/gist/6754242cff544445aea8

Comment: hmm let my try once more then because it diddnt work properly so ill also check in notepad++ to see if there are some extra unseen special characters

Comment: if i paste the line inside notepad++ i see that its like this: STX*NTF,CTRL,SQL,OPEN,9,-70ETXSTX etc what are the 'STX' and 'ETX'?

Comment: @GiovanniLeGrand http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character

Comment: Your new question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799631/removing-control-characters-from-a-utf-8-string

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  The output you show couldn't possibly come from the code you posted.  The input string shown at the top of the question does not have the characters `,80` and `,81`.  Please update your question so it properly demonstrates the problem you are having.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know you said "preferrably with regex" but this is cleaner IMHO with `String.Split`:

```
string s = "*blablablab,blablabla,blablabla,blablabla*blablabla,blabalbal,blablabla*";
string[] results = s.Split(new [] {'*'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

results:

```
String[] (2 items)
----------------------------
blablablab,blablabla,blablabla,blablabla 
blablabla,blabalbal,blablabla
```

One thing to remember with `String.Split` is that is your string *begins* or *ends* with a delimiter you'll get empty entries at the beginning and end, respectively, of the resulting array.  Adding the `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` parameter removes those empty entries so you are just left with the two stings between each pair of asterisks.

Comment: This would also include strings before the first asterisk and after the last, e.g. from `"asdf*1*2*asdf"` you would no only get `"1"` and `"2"` but also the `"asdf"` before and after. Not sure yet what the OP expects in that case, but the "between" in the title suggests that it might not be desired.

Comment: i've tried this and tried to show it in a textbox using:data = sp.ReadExisting().ToString();
            string[] tmp = data.Split(new [] {'*'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            foreach(string word in tmp){
                    COM_PORT_INFO_BOX.Text += word + "\r\n";
            }

but it still results in giving me cuts between words like this:
NTF,CTRL,SQL,OPEN,+,-66

NTF,CT
RL,DBUSY
,ON,+,-6
3

NTF,CT
RL,DBUSY
,OFF

NTF,CT
RL,SQL,C
LOSE

Comment: the end CLOSE is seperated after the C

Comment: You must have some embedded whitespace or control characters.  That has nothing to do with `string.Split` and your result wouldn't be any different using regex.  I would use the debugger to look more closely at those characters and see if you can filter them out.

Comment: @GiovanniLeGrand What you've written here does not match the question you've asked in the least. Could you update your question with the exact example? The answer provided is valid for your `blabla` string.

Comment: sorry i've edited and approved the suggested edit with a real example

Answer (score -1):

This works for me on regexr.com

The Problem with your regex was, that the ending "*" needs to be used as the ending of the first and the beginning of the second entry. But since it's already used for the first, it's ignored in the second one.

Thats why I used the "\2" backreference

```
\2(.+?)(\*)

\2 -> backreference to the second group (\*)
(.+?) -> every character until a "*" is found
(\*) -> The character thats ending a single Entry
```

Comment: for what is the: \2 ?

Comment: Added explanation for each regex expression

Comment: There's just no need to use a regex, so I downvoted.

Comment: I don't see a reason to down vote, because I used regex since this the topic was "How can I find the value between '*' and '*' with regex?".

Comment: @NikyBrettschneider: with all of these questions, you can't just take the face value of the question, because the people who ask often don't formulate their problem correctly. In any case, you didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score -2):

try this one

```
([^\*](\.*)[^\*])*
```

it worked on http://regexstorm.net/tester

```
[^\*] = match any character which is not *
(\.*) = match any character

so the regex explanation is 
at first match any character that is not *, then match any character that does not ends with *
```

i think logically true and i tried it and it matched

hope it will help you

Comment: Have a look at what this regex actually does. Because I doubt it works as you expect. [Visual Regex Preview (Debuggex.com)](https://www.debuggex.com/r/rHo-qzkep_2Rl6Oy)

Comment: i've tried this but while trying to use this it already gives me the error: Unrecognized escape sequence

Comment: @GiovanniLeGrand: you shouldn't be using this answer, but if you did go this route, you have to make sure you use C#'s special string literal: `@"([^\*](\.*)[^[\*])*"` (note the @ at the beginning).

Comment: i gave you the solution using C# try it on the link i gave you please