# Visual Studio 2012 Natvis skip IndexListItems

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2012

I am creating a natvis file for the Qt classes and I ran into a problem.

In order to visualize QHash objects I created these two types:

```
<Type Name="QHashNode&lt;*,*&gt;">
    <DisplayString Condition="next->next == 0">{{ key={key} value={value} h={h}}}</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString>{{ key={key} value={value} h={h} withCollision }}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="NextNode">reinterpret_cast&lt;QHashNode&lt;$T1,$T2&gt; *&gt;(next)</Item>
    </Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name="QHash&lt;*,*&gt;">
    <DisplayString>{{ size={d->size} buckets={d->numBuckets} }}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <IndexListItems>
            <Size>d->numBuckets</Size>
            <ValueNode Condition="reinterpret_cast&lt;QHashNode&lt;$T1,$T2&gt; *&gt;(d->buckets[$i]) != e">reinterpret_cast&lt;QHashNode&lt;$T1,$T2&gt; *&gt;(d->buckets[$i])</ValueNode>
        </IndexListItems>
    </Expand>
</Type>
```

It pretty much works, but since the QHash is not continuous in memory, there are a lot of invalid entries. 
The condition

```
reinterpret_cast&lt;QHashNode&lt;
$T1,$T2&gt; *&gt;(d->buckets[$i]) != e
```

already filters those out that are invalid, but they are still shown as `<Unable to display value>`.

Does anyone know if there is a way to completely skip those entries?

I never really worked with the autoexp.dat file which was the old way to do it, but when looking at the file with the Qt-plugin installed it seems to me that the statement

```
#switch ($e.next != 0) #case 1 (
    $e
)
```

does exactly that, so I hope that there maybe is a way to do it in the natvis file as well?

If anyone's interested, I can give you the natvis file, but I only have QString, QByteArray, QList, QVector, QMap and (the problematic) QHash until now.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem with my hash container. I also found this feature request that I voted for: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3712689-implement-the-features-missing-in-natvis-that-auto

Comment: ! = e needs to have a .gt for the *

Comment: check [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/06/28/using-visual-studio-2013-to-write-maintainable-native-visualizations-natvis.aspx). may be it helps you...

Answer (score 2):

According to the [MSDN page on writing type visualizers](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Writing-type-visualizers-2eae77a2), `<IndexListItems>` are by definition contiguous:

> **IndexListItems Expansion**
>
> ArrayItems assume array elements are laid out contiguously in memory. Debugger gets to the next element by simply incrementing its pointer to the current element. To support cases where you need to manipulate the index to the value node, index list items can be used. Here’s a visualizer using 'IndexListItems' node: [....] The only difference between ArrayItems and IndexListItems is that the 'ValueNode' expects the full expression to the ith  element with the implicit '$i' parameter.

Also, might I point you at [the Qt Labs VSTools repository](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt-labs/vstools) and [its documentation](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/QtVSAddin)? In particular `tools/Qt4EEAddin/qt5.natvis` looks a great deal like what I think you're trying to write? (Or is it *actually* what you're writing? ^_^) Either way, I think the best you can do is what is in `qt5.natvis`, which has a special `<DisplayString>` for empty `QHashNodes` but does not try to elide empty buckets in the `QHash`.

Comment: This answer/statement is very much incorrect. The documentation says "<ArrayItems> are laid out contiguously in memory" not that <IndexListItems> are laid out contiguously. IndexListItems is provided as a way to use indexing whereas ArrayItems does not. I'm commenting so others do not get misled when searching for natvis help.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me, just html tags.

replace it with '<' , '>'

more information, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904051/is-there-c-function-that-replace-xml-special-character-with-their-escape-seque)