# Operator < is not defined for types 'char' and 'integer'

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, char, hex

I am trying to convert a block of code from C# to VB.NET. The original code sample can be located here (see the accepted answer):

[How do you remove invalid hexadecimal characters from an XML-based data source prior to constructing an XmlReader or XPathDocument that uses the data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762/how-do-you-remove-invalid-hexadecimal-characters-from-an-xml-based-data-source-p)

I've done a crude conversion using [an online tool](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) although I have an exception at the point where `ch` char object is being checked against the range of hexadecimal characters.

`If (ch < &HFD AndAlso ch > &H1F)`

The exception raised is `operator <  is not defined for types 'char' and 'integer'`. Where am I going wrong with the VB interpretation?

```
Function RemoveTroublesomeCharacters(inString As String) As String
    If inString Is Nothing Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    Dim newString As New StringBuilder()
    Dim ch As Char

    For i As Integer = 0 To inString.Length - 1

        ch = inString(i)
        ' remove any characters outside the valid UTF-8 range as well as all control characters
        ' except tabs and new lines
        If (ch < &HFD AndAlso ch > &H1F) OrElse ch = ControlChars.Tab OrElse ch = ControlChars.Lf OrElse ch = ControlChars.Cr Then
            newString.Append(ch)
        End If
    Next
    Return newString.ToString()

End Function
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C#, char is implicity convertable to int16, therefore the inequality test makes sense.

In VB.Net that implicit conversion is not allowed, therefore you have to act yourself.

The easiest way to achieve this is usually the `Asc()` method (to convert a char to an int) or the `Chr()` method (to go the other way).

For example:

```
If (Asc(ch) < &HFD AndAlso Asc(ch) > &H1F) OrElse...
```

I've come across this as an issue with the developerfusion conversions a couple of times lately, so I've raised a suggested change [here](http://feedback.developerfusion.com/forums/5477-code-converter/suggestions/4677641-c-operations-that-include-char-and-int-don-t-conv). Give it a vote if you want it fixed!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Chr()` or `Asc()`

`Asc()`  --> Returns an Integer value representing the character code corresponding to a character.

`Chr()` --> Returns the character associated with the specified character code.

```
       If (Asc(ch) < &HFD AndAlso Asc(ch) > &H1F) OrElse ch = ControlChars.Tab OrElse ch = ControlChars.Lf OrElse ch = ControlChars.Cr Then
            newString.Append(ch)
        End If


       If (ch < Chr(&HFD) AndAlso ch > Chr(&H1F)) OrElse ch = ControlChars.Tab OrElse ch = ControlChars.Lf OrElse ch = ControlChars.Cr Then
            newString.Append(ch)
        End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Asc` to get the code of the character:

```
Asc(ch) < &HFD AndAlso Asc(ch) > &H1F
```