# Remove special character from DataTable

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, special-characters

I've a `DataTable` which I use to write it to `Excel` using below code. I use `using ClosedXML.Excel` to export it to Excel

```
var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add(dataTable, "Report");

Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename="Report.xlsx");

using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                workbook.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                MyMemoryStream.Close();
            }

Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

The above code throws error for the special character: **'', hexadecimal value 0x1A, is an invalid character.** I'm unable to copy the special character here. So please apologize.

I saw below post to replace the special character in the post [C# hexadecimal value 0x12, is an invalid character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21053138/c-sharp-hexadecimal-value-0x12-is-an-invalid-character)

```
static string ReplaceHexadecimalSymbols(string txt)
{
string r = "[\x00-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x26]";
return Regex.Replace(txt, r,"",RegexOptions.Compiled);
}
```

Could anyone guide me on how I can convert `DataTable` value to `string` and back again from `String` to `DataTable`.

Or please let me know if there is any other approach to tackle this `special character` issue?

Comment: do u want to remove Special Character?

Comment: On which row is the exception thrown? `workbook.Worksheets.Add(dataTable, "Report");` ?

Comment: @Raj, If possible I would like to export with Special Character, else, I'm ok to remove it since Export is priority & not special character. 
@Magnus, I get error at line `workbook.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);`

Comment: I've seen that version of the ReplaceHexadecimalSymbols() function quoted in several articles.  Note that if you data contains an & character, this function will just drop it.  So your Excel will now something like "Barnes  Noble".  This might not be what your users are expecting.....!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to replace the invalid string values in the `DataTable` you can do something like the following:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        if(dt.Columns[i].DataType == typeof(string))
            row[i] = ReplaceHexadecimalSymbols((string)row[i]);
    }
}
```

Do it before you add it to the `workbook`