# Get an element from a large html file

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, regex

I have a big html file (80 mo) like :

```
<html>
   <head>...</head>
   <body>
      <div class="nothing">...</div>
      <div class="content">
         <h1>Hello</h1>
         <div>
            <div class="phone"> ... </div>
            <div class="phone"> ... </div>
            <div class="phone"> ... </div>
         </div>
         <div>
            <div class="phone">
               ...
               <div>
                  ...
               </div>
               ...
            </div>
            <div class="phone"> ... </div>
         </div>
         <div>
            <div class="phone"> ... </div>
            <div class="phone"> ... </div>
            <div class="phone"> ... </div>
            <div class="phone"> ... </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

I can't modify this html file manually, so the best is that it stays read-only.

I would like to store each line of `<div class="phone"> ... </div>` in a table of string to be able to manipulate it later. Inside that div, there are also other elements that can be anything.

1. I tried to use HtmlDocument and XmlDocument to load this file but the file is so big that i get an Out of Memory exception
2. I tried to use Regex to get all those elements in a table but i couldn't manage it.

The regular expression that i used is:

```
Regex.Matches(myHtml, "<div class=\"phone\">[\\p{L}\\s]*\\,*[\\p{L}\\s]*<div");
```

this regex takes every

```
<div class="phone"> ANY UTF8 char </div>
```

but the problem is : this regex takes all UTF8 char untill it finds the next `</div>` but this closing div is not necessarily the closing div of the first opening div.

Any ideas how i can make this? Can't we cut this file in different string to be able to load it in a htmlDocument?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the forward-only `XmlReader` or `XPathNavigator` methods?

Comment: XPathNavigator gets my vote; it should have the lowest memory footprint because you're querying the file instead of loading the entire thing into memory.

Comment: I get a problem with XPathNavigator. Something like "hexadecimal value 0x0C, is an invalid character". To solve it, it needs to use Regex.Replace... but i get a out of memory exception... (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21053138/c-sharp-hexadecimal-value-0x12-is-an-invalid-character)

So, i used XmlReader and it's working :) thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `XmlReader` class to read the file. `XmlReader`does not load the whole file into memory but allows you to move through the XML document node by node while parsing the document on the fly.

Example on how to read the content of all divs with class = phone:

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\A.html"))
{
     // Loop over all xml tags 
     while (reader.Read())
     {
          // Check we have a div whith attribute class = phone
          if(reader.Name == "div" && reader.GetAttribute("class") == "phone")
          {
               // Yes, so read until the corresponding closing tag and output content
               textBox1.AppendText(reader.ReadInnerXml() + Environment.NewLine);
          }
     }
}
```

For more details refer to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.xml.xmlreader(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: The problem with this code is that the ReadInnerXml() has the same kind of function as the Read(). Both move to the next tag.

For example, the ReadInnerXml occur, the pointer will go on the next <div class="phone"> and then when we arrive on the condition while, it jump again to the next tag... so it misses 1 tag...

Comment: I edited your code if you don't mind. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Still needed improvement

Comment: Actually, ReadInnerXml is equivalent to calling Read. ReadInnerXml reads untill the closing tag and changes the pointer of the reader to the next tag. After the first loop, the execution of reader.Read() changes again the pointer of the reader to the next tag. So meanwhile a tag is skipped.

<div class="phone"> ... </div>
<div class="phone"> this div is skipped </div> 
<div class="phone"> ... </div>

Comment: That's not true. ReadInnerXml eads to the end of the current tag. That is true. But only the call to Read does then make the next tag the current one. So no tag is lost with the current code version.

Answer (score -1):

You can loop all elements with the class `phone` with jQuery and store them in a `HiddenField`. Then on PostBack you can access those values and process them.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getValues() {
        var valueArray = new Array();
        var valueString = "";
        $(".phone").each(function (index, element) {
            //for demo store both in hiddenfield and javascript array
            valueArray.push(element.innerHTML);
            valueString += element.innerHTML + ",";
        });
        $("#<%=HiddenField1.ClientID %>").val(valueString);
    }
</script>
```

And in code-behind:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string valueString = HiddenField1.Value;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueString))
        {
            string [] valueArray = valueString.TrimEnd(',').Split(',');
            foreach (string s in valueArray)
            {
                //do stuff
            }
        }
    }
```